# Python if condition simplify

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

If it is possible to simplify if condition code in python.

```
download_mis = MisFromSite(id)

check_success = download_mis.getModelObject()
login_success = 'Login Failed'
if check_success is None:
    check_success = download_mis.loginSite()
    login_success = check_success

if check_success is None:
    check_success = download_mis.getMis()

if check_success is None:
    check_success = download_mis.convertOurformat()

if check_success is None:
    check_success = download_mis.saveModelObject()

if login_success is None:
    check_success = download_mis.terminateLogin()
```

I write a code to fetch data from the website. I am unable to fetch data without login. without data, I could not process the data. each and every function is relay previous function output, except terminateLogin function. once login was a success need to terminate the login cookie so terminatelogin function should run if any function executed or not.

Comment: I think this is quite common, check for `error` or `success` before moving on to next step, the syntax might be strange to you, you can change it to a function ex: `handle(check_success)` and `return` or stop, this would make you code cleaner I think

Comment: can you send a sample code for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not fully aware of your intention, but the code you provided can be simplified as this:

```
download_mis = MisFromSite(id)

# An ordered list of functions to execute
# Remember: don't use parenthesis as they result in execution of functions
functions = [download_mis.loginSite, download_mis.getMis,
             download_mis.convertOurformat, download_mis.saveModelObject,
             download_mis.terminateLogin]

# This function always executes
check_success = download_mis.getModelObject()
for function in functions:
    # if at any step result is not None then nothing will execute
    if check_success:
        break
    # otherwise next function executes until result is not None
    check_success = function()
```

Comment: Did you see `check_success = function()`?

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya As I mentioned I'm not aware of the intention of the OP, but as far as I can understand the code he provided, it's a simplified version of that.

Comment: once the login is done. I need to terminate a login cookie if any functions run successfully or not. @szamani20, please change code once login success I need to run the logout function. please change the condition on function name not index. this one missing `login_success = check_success`

Comment: @vignesh You should edit your question and include necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

I find it much more pythonic to raise exceptions whenever something fails. For instance, maybe `getModelObject' raises a`ModelFetchError`if it can't get the model. Perhaps`loginSite`raises`LoginError` if it can't log in. With that in place, your flow can be simplified to:

```
download_mis = MisFromSite(id)
download_mis.getModelObject()
download_mis.loginSite()
download_mis.getMis()
download_mis.convertOurformat()
download_mis.saveModelObject()
download_mis.terminateLogin()
```

Each line must succeed before the program can move on to the next one. If `convertOurformat` failed for some reason, `saveModelObject` would never be reached. You also get nice tracebacks explaining exactly what failed and where, basically for free.